# Constraint creation in SQL Server which includes case statement

Tags: sql-server, oracle, t-sql

I need to create a unique constraint to my one of SQL tables which will check two case statements also. This works fine in Oracle. But I can't make it work in SQL Server 2008. I'm putting both those queries here.

ORACLE (works fine):

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX UK2_TR_ASSESSMENTEMPLOYEE ON TR_ASSESSMENTEMPLOYEE
(CASE  WHEN ("EMPLOYEEID" IS NOT NULL AND "SCHEDULE" IS NULL) THEN NULL
ELSE "EMPLOYEEID" END , CASE  WHEN "SCHEDULE" IS NULL THEN NULL 
ELSE "SCHEDULE" END )
```

SQL Server :

```
Alter table TR_ASSESSMENTEMPLOYEE 
Add Constraint UK2_TR_ASSESSMENTEMPLOYEE Unique 
(
CASE WHEN EMPLOYEEID Is Not NULL AND SCHEDULE IS NULL THEN NULL ELSE EMPLOYEEID, 
CASE WHEN SCHEDULE IS NULL THEN NULL ELSE SCHEDULE 
)
```

Please save me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure it is possible in SQL server... Maybe try adding `END` keywords to your `CASE` statements, and try with the `CREATE UNIQUE INDEX` syntax instead of `ADD CONSTRAINT`, but I think it will not work. However I don't see the purpose of creating that kind of `UNIQUE` constraint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll prefix this by saying that the purpose of the Oracle constraint isn't completely clear to me.

It seems like the the second `CASE` statement in the Oracle example is redundant and could be simplified to the `SCHEDULE` column with no additional code, i.e.:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX UK2_TR_ASSESSMENTEMPLOYEE ON TR_ASSESSMENTEMPLOYEE
(CASE  WHEN ("EMPLOYEEID" IS NOT NULL AND "SCHEDULE" IS NULL) THEN NULL
ELSE "EMPLOYEEID" END , "SCHEDULE")
```

SQL Server doesn't support calculations in unique constraint criteria. One way to achieve similar behaviour would be to create a calculated column and base the constraint on that:

```
ALTER TABLE TR_ASSESSMENTEMPLOYEE 
ADD EMPLOYEEID_CALC AS (CASE WHEN EMPLOYEEID IS NOT NULL AND SCHEDULE IS NULL THEN NULL ELSE EMPLOYEEID END)

ALTER TABLE TR_ASSESSMENTEMPLOYEE 
ADD CONSTRAINT UK2_TR_ASSESSMENTEMPLOYEE UNIQUE 
(EMPLOYEEID_CALC,SCHEDULE)
```

However, this may not give you the behaviour you want - in SQL Server, `UNIQUE` constraints [do not allow duplicate `NULL` keys](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191166%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) (in violation of the ANSI SQL standard).

If you're on SQL 2008 or later you may be able to use a filtered unique index to get the behaviour you want (assuming that's to enforce uniqueness where `EMPLOYEEID` and `SCHEDULE` are both not `NULL`)

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX UK2_TR_ASSESSMENTEMPLOYEE 
ON TR_ASSESSMENTEMPLOYEE(EMPLOYEEID, SCHEDULE) 
WHERE EMPLOYEEID IS NOT NULL AND SCHEDULE IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: I think Ed's second solution is the way to go!  The assumes your are release level >= 2008, ie, supports filtered indexes.